# Python TKinter: Each item in a Python list becomes the title of a Tkinter checkbutton

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In Python, I have a list of names in a list data type [Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4]

Is there a way to code so that each item of the list becomes the text title of an individual checkbutton within a Tkinter Checkbutton widget which allows each name to be 'checked' as required by the user?

If possible, without importing any external modules other than Tkinter but all responses are valued

I need the checkbuttons to appear in this format:

```
[]Person1
[]Person2
[]Person3
[]Person4
```

where [] is a checkbutton that can be selected

Comment: I planned to use a "for" loop with the length of list as number of iterations but was not sure how to edit the "text" attribute of each individual checkbutton within the loop

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, i would do something like:

Easiest case:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

person = ["P1","P2","P3"]
result = {}

for i in person:
    result[i] = Variable()
    Checkbutton(master, text=i, variable=result[i]).pack()

master.mainloop()
```

This way all of the results go into the `result` dict

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. It is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know of a way to use .grid() instead of .pack() as I use .grid() in other parts of the interface?

Comment: Just put .grid() at the end. If you want to specify rows and columns you need to add a variable(s) for that and increase its value(s) through the iteration.

Comment: When using `grid`, you could also use `enumerate` to get tuples of `(index, element)` instead of manually incrementing a counter.